# Evaluate the following integrals/ Cauchy integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

So I have two questions. 1) Evaluate $$ \oint\limits_{|z|=1} \dfrac{\cos(\pi z^2)}{(z-2)(z-4)^3} dz$$ and 2)  Evaluate $$ \oint\limits_{|z|=6} \dfrac{\cos(\pi z^2)}{(z-2)(z-4)^3} dz.$$ Now I know the integrand is analytic when $ z\neq 2, 4$ so for 1) the integrand is analytic on $|z|=1$, do we not use cauchy's integral then?

I'm just confused because I only really understand the case for when one of the poles makes the integrand non-analytic. That's why for 2) I'm stuck as well because both $z= 2, 4 $ are included in $ |z|=6 $. We haven't learned the residue theorem yet either. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No I haven't because I wasn't enirely sure how to use that on this question. I think the expansion would be from solving $cos(\pi z^2)= A(z-4)^3+B(z-2)(z-4)^2+C(z-2)(z-4)+D(z-2)$ for the consants $A, B, C, D $... but that seems a bit tedious to work out. There must be a more efficent way.

Comment: Isn't the theorem "an integral of an analytic function over a closed curve equals zero" done before Cauchy's integral formula?

If you have that theorem then the first integral is 0 and the second one equals the sum of an integral around z=2 and an integral around z=4, then use Cauchy's integral formula (extended version for z=4).

Comment: Ohh I see, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For question one, $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $|z|<1$ hence by Cauchy's integral theorem $$\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz = 0.$$

For question two, we spot that $f(z)$ has poles at $z=2$ and $z=4$ (of order 3). Consider the first pole at $z=2$. Cauchy's integral formula states $$ \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{z-a}dz =g(a)2\pi i.  $$ Noting $g_1(z) = \dfrac{cos(\pi z^2)}{(z-4)^3}$ and $a=2$, $$ \oint_C \frac{g_1(z)}{z-a}dz =2\pi i \dfrac{cos(4\pi)}{(2-4)^3} = -\frac{\pi i}{4}. $$ Considering the pole at $z=4$, by Cauchy's differentiation formula, $$ \oint_C \frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz =\dfrac{g^{(n)}(a)2\pi i}{n!}.  $$ Noting $g_2(z) = \dfrac{cos(\pi z^2)}{z-2}$ and $a=4$, $$ \oint_C \frac{g_2(z)}{(z-a)^{n-1}}dz =\dfrac{g''(4)2\pi i  }{2!} = \dfrac{\pi i}{2}\left(-32\pi^2+\dfrac{1}{4}\right). $$ Finally, the original integral is the sum of these two integral, so $$\oint_{|z|=6} f(z)dz = \dfrac{\pi i}{2}\left(-32\pi^2+\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\pi i}{2}\left(-32\pi^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\right).$$

Comment: In the last but one statement, why is there (4-2) in the denominator of g′′(4)*2πi/(2!(4−2)) ?

Comment: @SuryaKLSV Sorry, made a hasty edit on this a few months ago, the $(4-2)$ shouldn't be there - well spotted.